# How to use Kubernetes e2e framework to build custom kubernetes tests

Tags: go, kubernetes, automated-tests, e2e-testing

I stumbled upon this [blog post](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/22/kubernetes-end-to-end-testing-for-everyone/), which describes the Kubernetes e2e test suite.

Unfortunately, there are not enough resources to explain how to use the framework to build custom tests that can run part of the CI pipeline.

How can I use that Go [framework](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/v1.12.0/test/e2e/framework)? or am I better off building my own framework using any Kubernetes clients' libraries?